# Find root with Newton's method

Tags: scheme, elisp, sicp, function-call, fixed-point-iteration

I write the `newton-method` to find root from Scheme example in elisp as

```
#+begin_src emacs-lisp :session sicp :lexical t
(defun deriv(g)
  (lambda (x)
    (/ (- (funcall g (+ x dx)) (funcall g x))
       dx)))

(defvar dx 0.00001)
(defvar tolerance 0.00001)

(defun fixed-point(f guess)
  (defun close-enoughp(v1 v2)
    (< (abs (- v1 v2)) tolerance))
  (let ((next (funcall f guess)))
    (if (close-enoughp guess next)
        next
      (fixed-point f next))))

(defun newton-transform(g)
  (lambda (x)
    (- x (/ (funcall g x) (funcall (funcall #'deriv g) x)))))

(defun newton-method(g guess)
  (fixed-point (funcall #'newton-transform g) guess))

(defun curt(x)
  (newton-method (lambda (y) (- (* y y y) x))
                  1.0))

(curt 12)
#+end_src

#+RESULTS:
: 2.2894284851069058
```

It works but observe the twisted code:

```
(defun newton-transform(g)
  (lambda (x)
    (- x (/ (funcall g x) (funcall (funcall #'deriv g) x)))))
```

Three `funcall`s, in which I could not imagine bad if more depths of closures.

Is there an alternative solution to the problem with elisp? (I guess it de-appreciates closures)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of the functions calls can be simplified, and we should implement @sds's advice regarding function names and conventions - like this:

```
(defvar dx 0.00001)
(defvar tolerance 0.00001)

(defun deriv (g)
  (lambda (x)
    (/ (- (funcall g (+ x dx)) (funcall g x))
       dx)))

(defun close-enough-p (v1 v2)
  (< (abs (- v1 v2)) tolerance))

(defun try (f guess)
  (let ((next (funcall f guess)))
    (if (close-enough-p guess next)
      next
      (try f next))))

(defun fixed-point (f first-guess)
  (try f first-guess))

(defun newton-transform (g)
  (lambda (x)
    (- x (/ (funcall g x)
            (funcall (deriv g) x)))))

(defun newton-method (g guess)
  (fixed-point (newton-transform g) guess))

(defun curt (x)
  (newton-method (lambda (y) (- (* y y y) x))
                 1.0))
```

Notice that we don't need to use `funcall` when invoking functions previously defined and named, such as `deriv` and `newton-transform`.

Comment: ty, I got the idea of separated 'try', more than 'write little function to work together", a helper function as try "abstraction"  is perspicuous than cumbersome "comments" inside to facilitate  a second reading.

Answer (score 2):

In `newton-transform`, `(funcall #'deriv g)` is identical to `(deriv g)`, so you can eliminate one of the 3 [`funcall`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Calling-Functions.html)s. The other 2 are, indeed, necessary.

Same for `newton-method`: replace `(funcall #'newton-transform g)` with `(newton-transform g)`.

**PS**. I strongly recommend either moving `defun close-enoughp` out of `defun fixed-point` or turning it into a [`cl-flet`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/cl/Function-Bindings.html). Lisp is not Scheme.

**PPS**. `close-enoughp` should be `close-enough-p`.

Comment: My Emacs claims that `flet` is obsolete (in elisp, not CL obviously) and you should use one of `cl-flet` or `cl-letf`.  I don't know modern elisp well enough to know the difference between these (or why `flet` is not the fight thing any more).